# Use Simulink.B​lockDiagra​m.arrangeS​ystem for signal line alignment but except one specific block

Tags: matlab, simulink

I am writing a script to automatically alignment for a Simulink model. I will find all subsystem blocks in my Simulink model and do alignment by using Simulink.BlockDiagram.arrangeSystem command. However,in one of subsystems, it included a TriggerPort as attached figure which leaded to this command did not work properly.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RltZH.png)

```
% Simulink model name
model = 'Sample_model';
% Open Simulink model
open_system(model);
% Find all Subsystems in model
subsystems =  find_system(model, 'FollowLinks', 'on', 'LookUnderMasks', 'all','LookUnderReadProtectedSubsystems','on', 'BlockType','SubSystem');
% Iterate through the list of Inports
for i = 1:length(subsystems)
    subsystemonebyone = subsystems{i};
    Simulink.BlockDiagram.arrangeSystem(subsystemonebyone, FullLayout='true'); 
end
% Save and close Simulink model
% save_system(model);
% close_system(model);
```

What I expected from that script that, after running, the result should be like:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VG1wJ.png)

I had some directions here but I did not know which the exact command to support:
Trigger Simulink.BlockDiagram.arrangeSystem with each subsystems, and if the subsystem blocks include Process trigger block, this command for all components inside except Process trigger.
Hold the Process trigger as fixed position all the time.
Anyways, because I do not know which command will be available here. Thus, please help me do this or guide me some ideas.

Comment: i guess one approach would be to arrange the whole model as you did and then afterwards set the position of the trigger with set_param

Comment: If after I ran this script and set the position of the trigger with set_param, the only position of trigger is changed. However, the position of inputs will be kept as the first image. Thus, I do not think it is a solution. I am finding a way to Simulink.BlockDiagram.arrangeSystem command can be applied for all blocks without Trigger block

Comment: i get what you mean, still is a bit better than having the trigger mixed in with the inputs. What if you remove the trigger block, reorder, add the trigger block again?